# mySQL - Is this query possible

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if it is possible to get this done by a query:

I have a table of bids done on different products

```
bid_id, product_id, date, price
```

bid_id is an incremented key, 
product_id is foreign key from another table of product details.

I would like to select all bids that raised the bid price on a product.
With what I have in this table, can it be done?

Let me try to make my myself clearer: For each product I would like to get all the dibs that raised the price from the previous bid.

For example: If the table contains

```
1, 12202, "2013-09-08 13:41:45", 120
2, 17394, "2013-09-08 13:43:32", 250
3, 12202, "2013-09-08 13:54:11", 170
4, 12202, "2013-09-08 14:05:37", 210
```

I would like to get lines 3 and 4 as output. (there can be several lines for one product)

Thanks!

Comment: Please, do not hesitate to post sample of data and desired output.

Comment: A bit of rubber ducking and Math 101 logic may help yuo a lot throught the whole of your career, you know. Have you asked yourself **why it wouldn't be possible?**

Comment: Do you still think that my math is lacking after I updated the post?

Comment: It's probably possible to do this with sql, but it's probably easier to do it with application code such as .net or coldfusion.  Is that option available to you?

Comment: It is available and it it how it do it now, but I guess that if I it is possible to do it using sql the performance would probably be much better, don't you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By "raised the price", I presume you mean that the bid is higher than any previous bid on the product.

If so, the answer is "yes".  It can be done.

Oh, you probably want to see the query too.

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             (select max(b2.price)
              from bids b2
              where b2.product_id = b.product_id and
                    b2.bid_id < b.bid_id
             ) as prevmaxprice
      from bids b
     ) b
where b.price > prevmaxprice;
```

EDIT:

If you want to raise the price from the previous bid, the query is similar, but the subquery logic is a little different:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             (select b2.price
              from bids b2
              where b2.product_id = b.product_id and
                    b2.bid_id < b.bid_id
              order by b2.bid_id desc
              limit 1
             ) as prevprice
      from bids b
     ) b
where b.price > prevprice;
```